# Android Game Dev: Draw menus with SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a menu and level select screen for my Android game but I'm not sure how to go about doing so. I already have the game portion of my game which renders to a SurfaceView object so I was wondering should I also have the menus render to a SurfaceView? If so should it be rendering to the SAME surface view or should the game and each menu screen have their own?

Basically I want it set up like so in terms of the activity flow:

```
Main Menu > Level Select > Game
```

I currently have the level select set up as a regular Android UI .xml layout but since I scale the rendered image to fit whatever screen it's playing on I can't do that unless it's drawing to a SurfaceView.

Any help or advice is appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of supporting multiple screens, the standard `Android` layout system will surely do a better job since it's been polished to fit any screen size and density and provide a perfect user experience. My own experience tells me that it's much easier to implement kind of level select menu using the `Android` UI tools, then to draw it yourself on the `Canvas`. And it looks nicer!

Comment: Right now this is how I have it set up but it's causing me headaches since I have a grid of buttons for the level select screen and a static background image and the buttons have to line up perfectly to the background image. So when I have a screen that isn't a 5:3 ratio the layout elements shift around and the background image gets squashed/stretched. Plus I'm trying to do it like the pros do and I doubt they use `Android` because it makes it dependent on the Android OS.

Comment: @StickFigs, Actually it's up to you how your layout will look. It's not impossible to create a layout that will look nice on nearly every Android-powered device, there's just a need for some effort. Head to www.developer.android.com, there are plenty of posts on supporting multiple screens, following them you'll have no problems implementing your layout.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm having trouble finding the posts you speak of. It doesn't appear that there is a forum at that address.

Comment: @StickFigs, Here's a nice new tutorial on that topic: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html. Search the site and you'll find more posts covering supporting multiple screens theme.